# RegionFunction parametric or piecewise definition

Tags: plotting, options, parametric-functions

Hi I want to plot a contourplot of a given surface over an specific region only. I have used the RegionFunction option for it. Now the problem is that the regions I need to plot are defined by parametric curves and or piecewise functions depending on the case. Which I don't know how to implement in combination with RegionFunction. Here a mere example of what I've done

```
Show[ContourPlot[V[x, y] + GG[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 2, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x - 1 < 0.36397 y], 
  GridLines -> Automatic],
 ParametricPlot[{(s - 0.28 Sin[2 Pi*s/Sqrt[4*2]])/
    Sqrt[2], (s + 0.28 Sin[2 Pi*s/Sqrt[4*2]])/Sqrt[2]}, {s, 0, 
   2 Sqrt[2]}]
 ]
```

[image]

And what I really want to achieve is  something like this gimp manipulated plot. where the plot region is defined by everything above my parametric curve

[image]

Comment: can you provide `V` and `GG`?

Comment: maybe using `ParametricPlot[{(s - 0.28 Sin[2 Pi*s/Sqrt[4*2]])/Sqrt[2], 
  v (s + 0.28 Sin[2 Pi*s/Sqrt[4*2]])/Sqrt[2]}, {s, 0, 2 Sqrt[2]}, {v, 
  0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[1, White], Mesh -> None]`?

Comment: the exact V and GG are really long to include in the question, both can be any z=f(x,y) function let us say Sin[2Pi(x-y)]. The idea is to cut the surface along the parametric curve in blue. So although your comment works to imitate the desire result in ContourPlot[] may not be generalized to let's say Plot3D[]